# latexmk Update view when compiling

Tags: latexmk, live-preview

When I use latexmk with the following command:

```
latexmk -pvc -pdf main
```

It seems to update the pdf file, but doesn't update the preview. How do I get it to update the xpdf preview shown when making changes? When compiling it shows this:

```
For rule 'update_view', running '&do_update_view( 1 1 0 1 )' ...
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on latexmk. But typing `man latexmk` in the terminal provides the manual. There I searched for "xpdf" and found:

> Arranging to use a command to get a previewer explicitly updated
>   requires three variables to be set. For example:
>
> ```
> $pdf_previewer = "start xpdf -remote %R %O %S"; 
> $pdf_update_method = 4; 
> $pdf_update_command = "xpdf -remote %R -reload";
> ```

So it seems that you need to write a small config file for the use with xpdf.

By the way: there are many pdf-viewers today. Why xpdf?